# Comparing elements of a list with those of sublists python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I'm trying to write a function which would take a value from a list, and then see if it's in the range of two values in a sub-list. Hopefully my code will explain it better:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
answer = []
c = 0
for elem in list1:
    if list2[c] <= int(elem) <= list2[c+1]:
        answer.append(elem) 
        sys.stdout.write(str(answer) + ' ')
        c += 1


Expected Output: 
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

So what I'm trying to do is see if the value of the element in list1 is in the range of each sub-list in list2, of course the values are added to a list and then printed out. 
I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Task11.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "Task11.py", line 51, in main
    input_string()
  File "Task11.py", line 48, in input_string
    list_interval(input_list, query_values)
  File "Task11.py", line 16, in list_interval
    if int(list2[c]) <= int(elem) <= int(list2[c+1]):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Which I undestand, but I'm unsure of how to actually use the sublists in the way I mentioned.

Comment: Expected output might clarify more.

Comment: For one thing, the code you're providing doesn't match the code in the exception. Please copy-paste the exact code you're using instead of retyping it in the post.

Comment: The rest of the code doesn't really matter (e.g input_function) because they work without any issues, it's just this function being the problem.

Comment: Yes, but it's still better to copy-paste the part you're looking at. It still doesn't match after your edit, and further, this code will actually choke on the `for` line due to a SyntaxError. Your chances of getting good help rely on providing accurate details. People will often want to copy-paste your code into an interpreter to reproduce the error, so you need to make sure it will actually run and do what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension that finds all elements from `list1` in the range parameters specified in `list2`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [[1, 3], [2, 4]]

lst = [[c for c in list1 if c in range(x, y+1)] for x, y in list2]

print(lst)
# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

The [**`range()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) helps to create a range of numbers starting from its first parameter excluding the last parameter. It takes an optional step parameter also where you can specify the difference between adjacent numbers in resulting output. If empty means the step is 1.